# using tag inside table

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, amsmath

Say I write a table twice, and want the second table to have the same numbering as the first. With equations, I know how to do it. However, with tables this does not work. The following is what I thought it would be, but gives an error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 x = 1
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 x \not= 2
\tag{\ref{eq1}}
\end{equation}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{c}
 hello
\end{tabular}
\caption{this is a talbe}
\label{table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{c}
 hello
\end{tabular}
\caption{this is a talbe}
\tag{\ref{table}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Anyone any idea how to reference correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a trick. use `\tabtag{table}` before `\caption`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\tabtag}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\ref{#1}}%
\addtocounter{table}{-1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 x = 1
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 x \not= 2
\tag{\ref{eq1}}
\end{equation}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
 hello
\end{tabular}
\caption{this is a table}
\label{table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
 hello
\end{tabular}
\tabtag{table}
\caption{this is a table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
 hello
\end{tabular}
\caption{this is a table}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. That does work in a single file. However, I have multiple subfiles, and I'm referencing a table in a different subfiles. Then it does not work.

Comment: For me it works fine. Please edit your MWE and show  the problem